# Downsample or average data for both the value and time index using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a time-indexed pandas DataFrame, with pairs of numbers separated by one or several NaNs:

```
Time
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000    0.0186458125
1970-01-01 00:00:00.066   -0.0165843889
1970-01-01 00:00:00.068             NaN
1970-01-01 00:00:00.116             NaN
1970-01-01 00:00:00.118   -0.0113886875
1970-01-01 00:00:00.166   -0.0117582778
1970-01-01 00:00:00.168             NaN
1970-01-01 00:00:00.216             NaN
1970-01-01 00:00:00.218   -0.0122501875
1970-01-01 00:00:00.232   -0.0122501875
Name: X, dtype: float64
```

Now what I would like to achieve is to compute average of those pairs of numbers and place the result into middle time segment so that the result would look like the following:

```
Time
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000             NaN
1970-01-01 00:00:00.033    0.0010307118
1970-01-01 00:00:00.066             NaN
1970-01-01 00:00:00.068             NaN
1970-01-01 00:00:00.116             NaN
1970-01-01 00:00:00.118             NaN
1970-01-01 00:00:00.142   -0.0115734826
1970-01-01 00:00:00.166             NaN
1970-01-01 00:00:00.168             NaN
1970-01-01 00:00:00.216             NaN
1970-01-01 00:00:00.225   -0.0122501875
1970-01-01 00:00:00.232             NaN
```

I'm also planning to downsample the time down to fixed frequency of 1/500 of a second, so it's ok if there will be more intermediate NaNs than shown above. Is there a more or less simple Pandas way to do so?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more like a step by step solution I already break it down

```
df=df.to_frame('value')
df['key']=df.isnull().cumsum()

df['time']=df.index.map(lambda x : x.timestamp())# make datetime to numeric get the average
newdf=df.groupby('key').agg({'value':'mean','time':'mean'})# using groupby with agg
newdf.time=pd.to_datetime(newdf.time,unit='s')# convert float type datetime back to datetime format 
newdf=newdf.set_index('time').value
df.value=np.nan

df=df.value.combine_first(newdf)# combine_frist with new df with older one 
df
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000         NaN
1970-01-01 00:00:00.033000    0.001031
1970-01-01 00:00:00.066000         NaN
1970-01-01 00:00:00.068000         NaN
1970-01-01 00:00:00.116000         NaN
1970-01-01 00:00:00.118000         NaN
1970-01-01 00:00:00.133333   -0.011573
1970-01-01 00:00:00.166000         NaN
1970-01-01 00:00:00.168000         NaN
1970-01-01 00:00:00.216000         NaN
1970-01-01 00:00:00.218000         NaN
1970-01-01 00:00:00.222000   -0.012250
1970-01-01 00:00:00.232000         NaN
Name: value, dtype: float64
```